# How to extract values from the loop and plot them in matlab?

Tags: loops, plot

This is my simple code:

```
for i=-20:20;
  s=[-1 0 0];
  e=[1 0 0];
  r=[i 5 0];
  b=e-r;
  a=s-r;
  w=cross(a,b);
  y=dot(w,w);
  z=dot(a,b);
  u=norm(a);
  v=norm(b);
  k=dot(u,v);
  g=1;
  q=(w/y)*(u+v)*(1-z/k);
  V=g/4*pi*q
end
```

But even such simple i can not figure out how to plot the results (only Z components of the vector V). Please help?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a figure `f=figure();`

2) Put `hold on;` command such that you draw the points in the same figure without overwriting the previous plot commands;

3) run the loop and use a plot of your choice. such as `plot(i,z,'o');` here you draw a circle

Cheers
TL